# Compare list of string with string in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of string
Like list1 contain 'pinky','smita','Rashmi','Srivani'
And string is like
String str = "pinky, Nandini'
I want to check if neither of str present in list1,proceed further.
how to do that?

Comment: [Enumerable.Intersect Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0) - I think the result of this method should be empty in that case. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ctdmNn

Answer (score 2):

You can use combination of [`.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0) with [`.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-6.0) with `!`,

```
var list1 = new List<string>(){ "pinky", "smita", "Rashmi", "Srivani" };
string str = "pinky, Nandini";
var list2 = str.Split(",");

var nameExists = list2.Any(x => list1.Contains(x));
if(!nameExists)
{
   //Your code goes here.
}
```

---

As @Fildor said, you can use [`Intersect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0). Elegant approach,

```
//All credit goes to @Fildor
var nameExists = list1.Intersect(list2).Any();
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want to return false in the example case, so you can use `Any` method: Check if none of the elements of the list is already in the `str`, here is a one liner:

```
if (!list.Any(x=>str.Contains(x))) ....
```